# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/src/code/app/tasks/install.php on line 203 Failed to save Docker Compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, appwrite

I am getting this error, while trying to install the appwrite locally in my windows system

Error: `Warning: file_put_contents(/usr/src/code/appwrite/docker-compose.yml): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/src/code/app/tasks/install.php on line 203 Failed to save Docker Compose file`

I am using Hyper terminal and the UNIX script given by appwrite to install appwrite locally via docker

Comment: Where did you run the install command?

Also, I'm not sure what Hyper terminal is...I would have expected you to use the PowerShell or CMD command to install it on Windows.

Comment: i tried powershell and its working perfectly fine, tq @StevenNguyen, its not working with the hyper terminal

Comment: Ya...hyper terminal might have a different syntax for something or maybe emulating something that isn't compatible. I'm glad it's working with PowerShell!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend installing using CMD

```
docker run -it --rm ^
    --volume //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ^
    --volume "%cd%"/appwrite:/usr/src/code/appwrite:rw ^
    --entrypoint="install" ^
    appwrite/appwrite:1.2.0
```

or PowerShell

```
docker run -it --rm `
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock `
    --volume ${pwd}/appwrite:/usr/src/code/appwrite:rw `
    --entrypoint="install" `
    appwrite/appwrite:1.2.0
```

rather than Hyper Terminal. Hyper Terminal might not support docker.

Reference: https://appwrite.io/docs/installation#windows